# Suggestion For SEO Friendly URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, hyperlink, seo

I am displaying city list and details along with image gallery of that city on our one of the website.

I want to create an SEO friendly URL for the city details page and city album page.

Currently both the pages URL's are:

Rio De Janeiro City Details Page Link:
http://www.example.com/city/38/RioDeJaneiro

Rio De Janeiro City Album Page Link:
http://www.example.com/cityalbum/38/RioDeJaneiro

We had also come up with a few solutions as follows:

Rio De Janeiro City Details Page Link:
"Provide Link"

Rio De Janeiro City Album Page Link:
"Provide Link"

Please suggest if the above mentioned URLs are good for SEO purpose or we need modification in it.

If we need to modify it then please suggest what sort of a modification should be done to make these URLs absolutely SEO Friendly.

Eagerly wating for your answers.

Thanks.

Comment: what is 38  in the url ? can you remove that ?

Comment: "38" is the unique ID for the city. I cant remove that.

Comment: you can add some slug column in the table and use it as a unique identifier. That will be more  SEO Friendly.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to have the below URL
http://www.example.com/city/38/RioDeJaneiro

But instead of having 38 in the URL, make it as its current city zip or pin code. Google can read and understand any type of URL combinations. Bots are built to read and understand any URL names (Symbols numbers and alphabets).

I hope Google can understand the theory behind your URL.